Powershell script to capture the error response and headers of http request
I am getting 403 error randomly for an http request. To test this I am making a powershell script that hits http request and log the error response, headers and error code of all 4XX series errors. I am able to log both the error code, error response but not the headers.
Below is the script,
# Define the log file path
$logFilePath = "https_test_connection_log.txt"

# Function to log messages with a timestamp
function Log-Message {
    param (
        [string]$Message
    )
    $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value "$timestamp - $Message"
}

# Send a GET request to the API
try {
    # Make the HTTP GET request
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop

    # Log successful response details
    Log-Message "Request to $apiUrl successful."

    # Log response headers if they are available
    if ($response.Headers -ne $null) {
        Log-Message "Response Headers:"
        foreach ($header in $response.Headers.GetEnumerator()) {
            Log-Message "$($header.Key): $($header.Value)"
        }
    } else {
        Log-Message "No headers found in the response."
    }

    # Log the response body (converted to JSON if possible)
    $responseBody = $response.Content | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    Log-Message "Response Body: $responseBody"
}
catch {
    # Log the error message
    $errorMessage = "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    Log-Message $errorMessage

     # Log the response body (converted to JSON if possible)
    Log-Message "Error Response: $_.ErrorRecord.Exception"

    # Check if an error response is available
    $ErrorResponse = $_.ErrorRecord.Exception.Response

    # Log the error response body if available
    $ErrorContent = (New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($ErrorResponse.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd()
    Log-Message "Error Response Body: $ErrorContent"

    Log-Message "Error Response Headers:"
    foreach ($header in $ErrorResponse.Headers.GetEnumerator()) {
        Log-Message "$($header.Key): $($header.Value)"
    }
        
}

I tried using both invoke-webrequest and invoke-restmethod, I am getting empty headers.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Note that Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) 7.x have different header types. Windows PowerShell uses WebHeaderCollection whereas PowerShell 7.x uses HttpResponseHeaders. They are enumerated differently, the WebHeaderCollection.GetEnumerator() iterates over the keys only, whereas HttpResponseHeaders iterates over key/value pairs. Your code would work for PowerShell 7.x, but not for Windows PowerShell.
